# Highlight cells based on row number on VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I want to change the cell style based on the row number. I am still new on VBA. 
Here is my code:

```
Sub format()
    FinalRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 1 To FinalRow 
        If Rows.Count = 2 * i + 1 Then
            Selection.Style = "Good"
        ElseIf Rows.Count = 2 * i Then
            Selection.Style = "Bad" 
        End If

        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
   Next i
End Sub
```

The loop moves to the next cell but does not highlight if a criteria is met. May you please help me.

Comment: Your criteria doesn't make sense. Can you explain which cells should be "good" and which "bad"? Or give a example data?

Comment: I basically want all the odd row numbers to be "good" and all the even row numbers to be "bad" irrespective of the data that is in (for e.g.) Column A.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I think you missused `Rows.Count`.
`Rows.Count` returns the total number of rows of your sheet. So now your criteria is only highlighting the two rows that are in the middle of the sheet.

If I assume correctly that you want to put "Good" the Rows that are even and "bad" the ones that are odds. then you should change your code to something like this:

```
Sub format()
    FinalRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 1 To FinalRow 
        If i/2 = int(i/2) Then
            Selection.Style = "Good"
        ElseIf (i+1)/2 = int((i+1)/2) Then
            Selection.Style = "Bad" 
        End If

        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
   Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: You don't need a second criteria if it is not even it *must* be odd, so `Else` would be enough, also using `.Select` is a very bad practice, see my answer.

Comment: I agree, I just wanted to leave it as close to the code in the question as possible

Comment: Also you should use `i Mod 2 = 0` to test for even instead of `int(i/2)`, because Excel has more rows than `Integer` can handle and therefore it will crash if you have more than `Integer` rows with data. If you handle row counts you must use at least `Long`.

Comment: You guys are amazing. Thank you very much. I appreciate it.

Comment: Sorry guys, how do I modify the existing code to take into account multiple columns too?

Answer (score 3):

I suggest the following:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub FormatEvenOddRowNumbers()
    Dim FinalRow As Long
    FinalRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To FinalRow
        If i Mod 2 = 0 Then 'even row number
            Cells(i, 1).Style = "Good"
        Else 'odd row number
            Cells(i, 1).Style = "Bad"
        End If
   Next i
End Sub
```

To test if a row number is "even" you can use `If i Mod 2 = 0 Then` also you don't need to test for "odd" because if it is not "even" it must be "odd" so you can just use `Else` without any criteria.

Try to avoid using `.Select` it makes your code slow. See [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba). Instead access the cells directly like `Cells(row, column)`.

Comment: Sorry guys, how do I modify the existing code to take into account multiple columns too?

Comment: be more clear about what you mean by multiple columns.

Comment: So currently the macro runs only on a single column If I want the style on say column A and B I would have to run the macro on both columns individually. I would want to change the cell styles not just on one column at once, but on 2 or more column at once.

Comment: You can either use `Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 5)).Style` to do it for column 1 to 5 or use `Rows(i).Style` to color the entire row.

Comment: Thank you PEH. I appreciate it.